# What does Hinduism say about removing evil eye from Elderly persons?

Tags: nazar, evil-eye

How to remove Nazar, ie Evil Eye in Elderly person

He had bad life, ie was refugee at age of 5, lived through 3 wars.

Migrated to USA 50 years ago, had horrible married life

He tries to keep good health, looks several decades younger.

About a year ago his dentist was admiring that he looks young for age.

That day his knee became worse. Knee Dr says he has severe osteoarthritis. If he does not het treated he will end up in wheelchair

He cannot go for surgery because around the same time Cardiologist says he has severe aortic stenosis and needs TAVR (he is height risk for open heart surgery)

His prostate problem got worse. Imagine having paining, burning urination, not.emptying your bladder completely

The 80 yr old never believed in Nazar till it happened to him. A year later he is suffering deeply

I am doing everything I can to help him

How to get rid of this evil eye? We live in apartment building so it’s not like we can burn anything at the entrance of our home

This is very upsetting. Now he learned not to unnecessarily share good information about himself.

How to get rid of nazar?
How to block nazar?

By the way he is from Sikh/Hindu family, if that is relevant.

Comment: Perform graha yajna.

Comment: What is graha yajan?